# Cannot update datatype on temporal table to NOT NULL

Tags: temporal-tables

I need to change a column datatype to NOT NULL on a Temporal (system versioned) table. The attached history table has null values in the column that need to go away before it will let me make the change. I attempted to turn off system_versioning for the temporal table and make my update directly to the history table. I was not able to turn off system_versioning as it is referenced by a view.

Comment: There is no attached history table.  Please provide which database that you are working with by tagging your question.  You may want to review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Comment: There IS an attached or linked history table. It keeps track of all the updates, deletes, etc that happen to the Temporal (system versioned) table. Here is a snippet from a blog in case you are unfamiliar with temporal tables. "As a quick introduction, a temporal table keeps a record of all data changes by saving versions of rows in a separate history table, with a validity period attached to each version." It came from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2016/11/10/oops-recovery-with-temporal-tables/

Comment: It was the wording.  I was reading it that there was an attached history table to the post.  Sorry about that.

Comment: When you say that you were not able to turn off system_version because "it" is referenced by a view.  Are you saying that the temporal table is referenced by a view?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Here is the exact error I get. Cannot ALTER 'tblcustomers' because it is being referenced by object 'vw_ProviderContactValidationSearch'. I was really hoping that there was something built into these temporal tables that allow you to change data data types.

Comment: I believe that you will need to do a `DROP VIEW' in order to do what you would like to do.  The view is referencing the table as a source.  However, before you do that, you may want to obtain the SQL used to create the view so that you can easily re-create the view once again.  (Right-click on view then copy the body of ALTER VIEW.)